# What tool or Program can be used to add "info pins" to custom fantasy maps

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, map-making

Firstly, Allow me to apologize if this is not relevant on on topic for this stack exchange, but I'm at a loss here and hope someone can help.

I have created a rough map for my world using Krita (Similar to Gimp) which i use for internal reference while doing other world building.

What I am looking for is a program or tool (offline not cloud based) that will allow me to drag and drop "pins" onto it which when hovered over will display text (or can be clicked on for the text either works) the way Pins work on services such as google maps.

I am currently using the classic method of putting "1" "2" "3" etc. on the map and having a separate legend file which references them, but it's seriously clunky.

Google has failed me no matter what I've tried.

Dose anyone here know of something that fits what I'm looking for, or a better answer that hasn't occurred to me.

I'm mainly trying to do this for the small things, Specific bridges, monuments, and other points of interest that otherwise don't warrant their own specific legend markings.

Again I'm sorry if this is to far off-topic, but as it relates to world building it seemed like it fit and I can't think of a better place to ask.

Edit:
The answers that have come in while informative have not resulted in what i'm after (clearly due to poor phrasing on my part)
I'm really looking for a downloadable program that is not web or cloud based, similar to using Ms word, instead of google docs.
I have the image i wish to use as the map i just lack the ability to pin or annotate it.

~lin

Comment: Not really a tool, but a crude solution could be to hack together a simple html page with some simple Javascript or CSS to trigger the effect you want.

Comment: I can't think of an app per say, but something like imagemap in html may be useful? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp

Comment: Other thoughts. Campaign Cartographer can do this, but I can't remember if you can use it outside of the program. And I'm 90% certain you can do it in a pdf too

Comment: How is this not a shopping question?

Comment: @ZeissIkon, we normally allow question about worldbuilding resources like software in this case

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Okay, I wasn't sure enough to downvote or close vote.

Comment: to the OP: don't worry, this kinda question is on topic here.

Comment: @Riddles and spoki0. That might be a good way for me to put something together, but more importantly perhaps, is it gives me new keywords to run through google to do continued research, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have found an answer. (I believe the correct thing is to post it as an answer for future readers yes?)

Using GIS software dose everything I needed, specifically QGIS.
Using Vector Layers set to the "point" type.

I found help with this over at the cartographers guild.

Thread where answer was found (including a tutorial that was kindly provided):
https://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?t=46382

Software that solved the problem, direct link.
https://qgis.org/en/site/

Comment: Yes; you're allowed and encouraged to answer your own questions . I was also going to suggest [Azgaar's FMG](https://azgaar.github.io/Fantasy-Map-Generator/), but depending on how much work you've done already, it may or may not be worthwhile, especially if you've already figured out something else that works well (and it's also an online tool, though you can *run* it locally). It's also *free*, unlike Inkarnate, but not sure how the features stack up. It does allow adding arbitrary info pins with notes, and has some import abilities.

Answer (score 4):

Inkarnate.
It lets you create a map and add notes, symbols, your own icons to the map.

Handy for worldbuilding.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen Inkarnate before but have been reluctant to use it due to it's online nature, and was unaware it could support the kind of notes i'm looking for. I'll give it a look and see if it can really fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

I've found another way I think - Worldanvil.com. It's a much larger package of Worldbuilding tools (I found it looking for timeline creation), and it looks like you can upload maps and add pins etc

Edit: Note however that not everything is available at the free level - this feature may need to be paid for.